# How to filter from the "many" side of a relationship?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I hope that you can help me with this. Apologies for not preparing an example file. 
The relevant part of my data model is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/170Pm6IcB167Tt83jjg4_UMYlQbsK1f-0/view?usp=sharing).

What I'm trying to do is creating a measure calculating the % of activities per customer filtering a specific "FeeType" (TypeA) from the Fees table, out.

I've tried:

```
NrofActivities = COUNT(Activities[CaseID])
```

```
ActivitiesNo_TypeA = CALCULATE([NrofActivities];
FILTER(ALL(Fees); NOT(
Fees[FeeType]="TypeA")))
```

```
Activities%GT_No_TypeA = DIVIDE (
                 [ActivitiesNo_TypeA];
                 CALCULATE([ActivitiesNo_TypeA];ALLSELECTED(Customers)))
```

The measure seems to be [working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14vPe5vLlAYaXH3e-F2Y6fTiiWwctjqxQ/view?usp=sharing) on a table with the activity types.

However it is [not working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ss0qyuKyp2asKJTQlN0A5JMto7ajY-p/view?usp=sharing) when matched with customers.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double-click the relationship and select both-way filtering. This feature should be used with caution.